# Вывод List<> на DataGridView WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms

Здравствуйте! Мне нужно сделать, чтоб пользователь вводил в TextBox'ы данные, они сохранялись в списке и добавлялись на DataGridView. Добавление в список я сделал, а вот как из списка данные вывести на DataGridView не знаю.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TransportSchedule
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public struct Transport
        {
            public string cityDeparture;
            public string cityDestination;
            public string dateDeparture;
            public string dateDestination;
            public double price;

            public Transport(string cityDeparture, string cityDestination, string dateDeparture, string dateDestination, double price)
            {
                this.cityDeparture = cityDeparture;
                this.cityDestination = cityDestination;
                this.dateDeparture = dateDeparture;
                this.dateDestination = dateDestination;
                this.price = price;
            }
        }

        List<Transport> transList = new List<Transport>();

        private void addButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Transport transport = new Transport(cityDepartureBox.Text, cityDestinationBox.Text, dateDepartureBox.Text, dateDestinationBox.Text, Double.Parse(priceBox.Text));
            transList.Add(transport);
        }
```

Comment: `dataGridView.DataSource = transList;`. И замените поля на свойства. И класс вместо структуры.

Comment: Я сделал так, но если вносить изменения в список (удалить элемент и тд), то эти изменения не отображаются на DataGridVIew, а мне нужно, чтоб изменения отображались

Comment: Вопросы не следует задавать в комментариях. И вообще, одна тема - один вопрос. По идее, нужно задать отдельный вопрос. А этот закрыть, дав на него ответ и приняв. По теме: вместо `List` нужно использовать `BindingList` или `ObservableCollection`.